# invalid configuration: webpack configuracion, is not an absolute path!

Tags: javascript, webpack

Agregando la configuración a webpack hace unos dias hice un webpack.config.js que cuando ejecuto en el entorno de desarrollo aparentemente en la ruta absoluta de los entry points esta mal escrita, creando las salidas antes funcionaba este es :

> output: {
>           path:'./dist',
>           filename: 'index.js'
>         },

```js
 const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); //installed via npm
const NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack'); //to access built-in plugins

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path:'dist',
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'webpack-dev-server',
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html')
    }),
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Como te dice el propio `webpack` tienes un problema con la configuracion de los entries y outputs.

Te sugiero que, como importas `path` al principio de tu fichero hagas lo siguiente:

- En primer lugar, crees una variable en la que obtengas el directorio actual

```js
const currentPath = path.resolve(__dirname)
```

- Luego, en tus rutas, sustituirlas por sus resoluciones con path:

```js
{
  entry: path.resolve(currentPath, 'src', 'index.js'),
}

{
    path: path.resolve(currentPath, 'dist'),
}
```

Con esto te quedaría un webpackConfig como este:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); //installed via npm
const NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack'); //to access built-in plugins

const currentPath = path.resolve(__dirname)

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.resolve(currentPath, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js'),
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(currentPath, 'dist'),
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'webpack-dev-server',
      template: path.resolve(currentPath, 'index.html')
    }),
  ]
};
```

Así, todas tus rutas serían absolutas y no tendrías ese problema.

Comment: He probado la config en el  [tag:webpack]webpack.config.js  que estoy haciendo escribi las rutas como esta en la doc, sin embargo la que enviaste me sigue dando el mismo problema por rutas absolutas

Comment: Tenia uina errata en el codigo, pruebalo ahora.